# Difference(s) between Solr's Cursor and ElasticSearch's Scroll

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, pagination, lucene

While looking for *pagination* with **Solr** and **ElasticSearch**, it turned out, both have the same "problem" (deep pagination, especially with shards). Though both search engines provide a solution/workaround for that:

- **Solr:** `cursor` https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Pagination+of+Results
- **ElasticSearch:** `scroll` http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html#scroll-search-context

Now I read those pages and searched the internet, but I'm still a bit clueless at some points:

- **`cursor` / `scroll` timeouts (garbage collection):**

  1. **Solr** documentations doesn't seem to provide a way for setting a timeout (or some special query to invalidate a `cursor` token). That's basically just a question about possible memory leaks, etc.
  2. **ElasticSearch** provides a timeout setting via `scroll=1m`.
- **backwards pagination:**

  1. **Solr** will provide a `cursor` token for each request, so it is possible to access any previous page.
  2. **ElasticSearch** seems to use always the same `scroll` token. So I cannot go backwards without doing a new search?
- **Alter search query:**

  1. **ElasticSearch** explicitly requires to use a special URL for `scroll` queries ( `http://localhost:9200/_search/scroll?scroll=1m?scroll_id=...`). So there's no possibility to alter the search query.
  2. **Solr** appends the `cursor` token to the normal query. Does this mean, that I can use some `cursor` token and change the query (filters, ordering, page size, etc.)?
- **Index changes while using `scroll` / `cursor`**:

  1. **Solr** documentation says, that if *the sort value of document 1 changed so that it is after the cursor position, the document is returned to the client twice*. That's clear to me. But now there are two more questions, which don't get covered:

     1. What happens if I use the `cursor` token for *page 2* (where *document 1* was before the sort value change)? Will I see the old items (including *document 1*) or will I see a new generated page with freshly calculated documents?
     2. Basically the same question as before: Solr documentation says: *the sort value of document 17 changed so that it is before the cursor position, the document has been "skipped" and will not be returned to the client as the cursor continues to progress*. If I use an old `cursor` token, will I be able to retrieve *document 17*? Or is it gone forever when using the current `cursor` token sequence?
  2. **ElasticSearch** documentation says nothing about what happens if the index changes while using `scroll`. I could imagine that it behaves the same as Solr, because both use Lucene for that functionality. **But** I'm completely unsure, because there's no information about that scenario.
- **How can this be faster than simple `size=10&from=10` / `rows=5&start=0`?**
  More kinda technical question, just because I'd like to understand what happens under the hood.

  - I just wondered how (especially) Solr can do this `cursor` thing more efficient than normal pagination using `start` and `rows`. Reason: (as said above) If a document changes, it will get reindex and can be placed after/before the current `cursor`. That sounds to me, like it has to reorder all documents. And that's basically the same as the default pagination!?

### EDIT:

- **ElasticSearch** documentation says *"A scrolled search takes a snapshot in time — it doesn’t see any changes that are made to the index after the initial search request has been made. It does this by keeping the old datafiles around, so that it can preserve its “view” on what the index looked like at the time it started."* So there's still the question: How does Solr handle this?

---

Would be cool, if someone could give me some explanation how things work.

Thanks in advance! `:)`

Comment: Did you ever get any answers on these questions elsewhere ?

Comment: This "question" seems to be the best comparison of these features so far. It will be nice to get more answers/comments on this.

Comment: "How does Solr handle this?" : 
SOLR does not take a snapshot at all, so new documents that would be returned AFTER the current cursor will be included in the results (even if the document is a duplicate of an earlier one already returned), new documents that would be returned BEFORE the position will not be returned at all. See https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Pagination+of+Results

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solr's `cursor` and `start` both function like open-ended range queries, with `cursor` operating like a less-than range query on **score** and `start` operating like a greater-than range query on **rank**. `cursor` is faster (especially for deep pagination) because, for a page size of 10, it only needs to hold in memory and sort at most the top 10 results, whereas `start=N` must hold in memory and sort the top N + 10 results, where N increases by 10 for each subsequent page. Both are sensitive to index modifications during pagination because each query runs against the current state of the index.

Elasticsearch's `scroll` functions like a single-use forward-only linear scan through a snapshot of the results of a fixed query which is guaranteed to return each document exactly once. It is not affected by index modifications because Elasticsearch remembers all the documents associated with the index at the time the "scroll context" was created by preserving the containing immutable segment files while the scroll context is alive. To avoid accumulating a stockpile of old segment files referred to by scroll contexts that will never be used again (perhaps because the client crashed), scroll contexts expire after a specified duration of time. My guess is that Elasticsearch supports neither jumping to arbitrary pages nor altering the query in order to optimize for scrolling efficiency.

You can partially emulate the behavior of Solr's `cursor` in Elasticsearch using an open-ended range query in which the upper/lower bound is set to the last value of the previous batch of results.

Comment: Following Chris's answer about Elasticsearch: there is a `search_after` option you can add to searches: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-search-after . It works exactly in that direction (plus: not locking the index's segments).